# asp.net c# better way to Parse numbers and datetimes from query string then try/catch

Tags: c#, asp.net

is there a better way then a try/catch to parse numbers and datetimes without crashing the page?

if they are not valid numbers/datetimes they should be null.

here is what I've got so far:

```
long id = null;
try{
    id = Int64.Parse(Request.QueryString["id"]);
}catch(Exception e){}

DateTime time = null;
try{
    time = DateTime.Parse(Request.QueryString["time"]);
}catch(Exception e){}
```

Comment: oh, alright, I can't believe I missed TryParse.....
I've been pulling an all-nighter and am pretty zoned right now, thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
int tempInt = 0;
if(int.TryParse(Request["Id"], out tempInt))
    //it's good!!
```

Likewise, for the date it's "DateTime.TryParse"

*edit*

To fully mimic what your code is doing, you'd have this:

```
long? id = null; DateTime? time = null;
long tempLong; DateTime tempDate;

if(long.TryParse(Request["id"], out tempLong))
    id = tempLong;
if(DateTime.TryParse(Request["time"], out tempDate))
    time = tempDate;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use TryParse instead of Parse.

TryParse doesn't throw and is good for situations like this, where the input is not necessarily trusted and you do not want an exception thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Have you noticed TryParse?

```
long id = -1;
if(Int64.TryParse(Request.QueryString["id"] ?? "", out id))
   // is valid...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use TryParse:

[Int64.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int64.tryparse.aspx)

[DateTime.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I usually do in my projects:

```
public long? ClientId
    {
        get
        {
            long? result = null;
            if (Request.QueryString[QueryStringConstants.ClientId] != null)
                result = Convert.ToInt64(Request.QueryString[QueryStringConstants.ClientId]);

            return result;
        }
    }


    public DateTime? ItemPurchasedDate
    {
        get
        {
            DateTime? result = null;
            if (Request.QueryString[QueryStringConstants.ItemPurchasedDate] != null)
                result = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.QueryString[QueryStringConstants.ItemPurchasedDate]);

            return result;
        }
    }
```

And I have defined my static class QueryStringConstants like this

```
public static class QueryStringConstants
{
 public static string ClientId = "clientId";
 public static string ItemPurchasedDate = "itemPurchasedDate";
}
```